# ASME latex class: indentation of first paragraphs

Tags: indentation

The ASME Latex class sadly activates indentations of first paragraphs. Do you know where this happens?

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/asme-journal-article-template/wspcsrrzjpmq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you shouldn't change the styles of journal classes, since they are designed that way to meet the requirements of the journal.  But if you really want to do this, you can use the `xpatch` package to patch `\@startsection`, which is where the relevant boolean is set.

This class loads the outdated `times` package, and probably shouldn't be used unless you have to submit to the journal (in which case you shouldn't mess around with it at all.)

**Explanation**

The way `\@startsection` is defined in the LaTeX kernel, it suppresses the indentation after the section heading only if the before skip value (the skip above the heading) is negative. In the standard classes, this skip *is* negative, and so the indentation in suppressed. But in the `asme2ej` class, it's positive, and so the indentation is not suppressed.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{asme2ej}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@startsection}{\@afterindenttrue}{\@afterindentfalse}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: yes, their class is crap. However, we might have to use. I still do not understand one thing: by default, Latex does not indent first paragraphs. And this class seems to change this, but where?

Comment: @pluton I've added an explanation.